# How to add the note in the history tab for a NetSuite form?

Tags: netsuite

Every time I edit the form, there is no any text appears in the "**NOTES**" field of "**History**" tab.

Please refer to the following picture:

[image]

How can we add notes for the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. That field is automatically set by Netsuite and we don’t have access to it